# Chrome (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID) errors on SSL self-signed certificate

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to setup a site on localhost using a self-signed certificate for [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) on Windows 10. Here is the Express.js server code.

*index.js*

```
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const httpsOptions = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl', 'ca.crt')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl', 'ca.key'))
}

const router = require('./router')

app.use('/people', router)

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(3443)
```

I have also imported the certificate authority *ca.crt* file to chrome, and restarted chrome. But I still have error on chrome as shown below:

[image]

Please guide how to solve this problem
Thanks

---

I created the keys and certificate using the following commands.

```
# certificate authority key
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out ca.key

# server key
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out server.key

# certificate authority
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -subj "/CN=Test CA/O=Test Organization" -out ca.crt

# certificate signing request
openssl req -new -key server.key -subj "/CN=localhost/O=Test Organization" -out server.csr

# server certificate
openssl x509 -days 365 -req -in server.csr -CAcreateserial -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -out server.crt

# verification
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ca.crt server.crt
```

---

**System Info**

- OpenSSL: 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
- Node: 7.7.1
- Windows 10

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294589/creating-self-signed-certificate-for-domain-and-subdomains-neterr-cert-commo), it seems to be similar to your issue

Comment: Your end-entity/server certificate is malformed. ***`CN=localhost`*** is wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Comment: @jww CN = Common Name, what does SAN stand for?

Comment: *SAN* might be `Subject Alternative Names`

Comment: Some of the answers posted here might also be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802552/2657515

Answer (score 11):

Spent a couple of hours trying to fix this. The following way worked for me:

Create a config file (for example req.cnf)

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
  [req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = VA
L = SomeCity
O = MyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = local.com
  [v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
  [alt_names]
DNS.1 = local.com
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

and then generate a certificate and private key

```
 openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 730 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout local.com.key -out local.com.crt -config req.cnf -sha256
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me while tested in windows server. Still getting the same error in chrome ERR_CERT_INVALID_COMMON_NAME

Comment: This was the correct magical incantation to make Chrome trust the cert for me - huge thanks! Small suggestion - when using `openssl` to generate the cert, specify the certificate as `local.crt` because, by default, Chrome's Certificate Import Wizard looks for `*.cer *.crt` so the next person along might not see their file.

Comment: Other tips for the next person: don't forget to import the cert in Chrome (Settings, search *Manage certificates*) in *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* and then restart Chrome `chrome://restart`

Comment: For debugging for me, I just had to visit the page once in the chrome browser I was using and click the "Proceed anyway" link, then it was good.

Comment: For anyone ending up here: to get chrome 108 to accept my self signed certificate for "localhost" on windows, this worked for me today but replacing "local.com" with "localhost" in the config file, and then adding the certificate as a Trusted Root Certification Authority